# How do I delete a single file from a folder?

Tags: php

How do I delete a single file from a folder? When I click my delete link, it removes all uploaded files from the folder.

The link:

```
<td><a href="Ad_delete.php?$Id=<?php echo $Row['Id'];?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this selected file ?')">Delete</a>
```

The code:

```
<?php

// Including the database connection file
include_once 'Ad_updbconnect.php';

// Getting Id of the data from url
$Id = $_GET['Id'];

$Del = glob('uploads/*'); // Get all file names
foreach ($Del as $File) {
    if (is_file($File)) {
        unlink($File); // delete file !
    } 
}

// Deleting the row from table
$Result = mysqli_query ($Con, "DELETE FROM ibgsec_uploads WHERE Id=$Id");
$Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);

// Redirecting to the display page.
header("location: Ad_uploads.php");
?>
```

This is the only thing left I'm working on, I've tried lots of ways to properly execute the command but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code explicitly deletes every file in uploads. What did you expect?

```
$Del = glob('uploads/*'); // Get all file names
foreach ($Del as $File) {
    if (is_file($File)) {
        unlink($File); // delete file !
    } 
}
```

Is `$Id` a file name? Seems risky but all the same you would want to try comparing that to `$File`. Compare *something* to `$File` otherwise you're just deleting them all.

You also are naming your param in the link `$Id`: `<a href="Ad_delete.php?$Id=<?php echo $Row['Id'];?>"` but fetching it as `Id`: `$Id = $_GET['Id'];`. Then you open yourself up to SQL injection by including that in the database query.